# How to test React component without Browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I have a react application that doesn't uses the [browserify](http://browserify.org/) tool. 
It means that the `React` variable is exported by the script of the react js lib called in the `<head>`.

```
// React variable is already available
var MyComponent = React.createClass({});
```

After implementing this component, I want to create a test for it.
I took a look at [Jest documentation](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html) and I've created my component test.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
jest.dontMock('../compiled_jsx/components/my-component.js');
describe('MyComponent', function() {
it('The variables are being passed to component', function() {
  var React = require('react/addons');

  // In the `MyComponent` import I got the error below: 
  // ReferenceError: /compiled_jsx/components/my-component.js: React is not defined
  var myComponent = require('../compiled_jsx/components/my-component.js'); 
});
```

In the [Jest documentation](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html) example, both component and its tests uses the `require` function for getting the `React` variable.

Is there any way to expose `React` variable into the component?
Or it's necessary using browserify for creating this test?

Answer (score 2):

Jest runs in node.js, so you need to use commonjs modules.  You don't use browserify with jest.    If you're really against commonjs modules you can do this assuming each file is wrapped in an iffe.

```
var React = typeof require === 'undefined' 
              ? window.React 
              : require('react/addons');
```

Or alternatively as the first line of your tests, try:

```
global.React = require('react/addons');
```

And either way, export your components using:

```
try { module.exports = Foo; } catch (e) { window.Foo = Foo };
```

---

Personally, I don't think jest is practical if you're not using commonjs modules.

Comment: I'm not using commonjs modules, but I'm using React and I didn't find a better way for testing my React application than Jest. I've thought about putting a `try/catch` treatment, but it seems ugly to me. I'm looking for a better way for doing it. 
Which test lib do you recommend instead of Jest?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jest is the best option, but mocha + react's test-utils should be good enough.  You'll either need to use karma + phantomjs, or a browser based test runner (I think mocha has one).

Comment: Alright. I think it's better adapting my application for using commonjs modules
. Thanks @FakeRainBrigand